# PromQL find helm deployments older than some days

Tags: timestamp, prometheus, promql

I have deployed the https://github.com/sstarcher/helm-exporter and have metrics in Prometheus containing deployment date (timestamp)
I want to find (in Prometheus) deployments older than some days (say, 180) and create an alert with that expression.
when I try 'helm_chart_timestamp <= (time() - 15552000)' it returns me no results (and even 'helm_chart_timestamp <= time()' ).
What would be the correct expression?

Comment: I found, that the metric value needs to be divided by 1000 because it's in msecs. 
helm_chart_timestamp/1000 < (time()-15552000)
But what would be an alert expression for AlertManager?

Answer (score 1):

seems good enough expression for alert is `((time() - helm_chart_timestamp/1000) / 3600 / 24 - 180 ) > 0`